# Android, Reading blank values

Tags: android

I'm new to android development, I trying to create a simply Pythagorean Calculator, I need help with reading if a lines blank, but still calculates instead of failing.

Here is my code

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText sideAObj;
private EditText sideBObj;
private EditText sideCObj;
private EditText outputObj;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sideAObj = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SideAInput);
    sideBObj = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SideBInput);
    sideCObj = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SideCInput);
    outputObj = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.OutputText);
}
public  void calculateClick(View v){
    try {
        double sideA = Double.parseDouble(sideAObj.getText().toString());
        double sideB = Double.parseDouble(sideBObj.getText().toString());
        double sideC = Double.parseDouble(sideCObj.getText().toString());



        if (sideAObj.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
            double pt = Math.sqrt((sideC * sideC) - (sideB * sideB));
            outputObj.setText(String.format("%.2f", pt));
        }

    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex){
        Toast errMess = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter Numbers Only",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        errMess.show();
        outputObj.setText(String.format("%2.f",0.00));
        return;
    }


}
public  void clearClick(View v){
    sideAObj.setText("");
    sideBObj.setText("");
    sideCObj.setText("");
    outputObj.setText("");
    sideAObj.requestFocus();

}
```

}
My program will calculate if their is a Zero on 1 line, but if I leave it blank the program fails entirely, whats the best way to prevent that.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint? Where exactly (at which line) it is failing? Also, just add an if loop check inside your calculateClick() method for the condition that the input is blank

Comment: I tried adding this if loop, but still failed if(sideAObj.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                Toast errMess = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Input Value",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                errMess.show();
            }

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will obviously fail as it doesn't know how to parse a blank value into a double. Just use something like this during instantiation itself:

```
double sideB = (sideBObj.getText().toString() == "") ? 0 : (Double.parseDouble(sideBObj.getText().toString()));
double sideC = (sideCObj.getText().toString() == "") ? 0 : (Double.parseDouble(sideCObj.getText().toString()));
```

Basically, you will be assigning the value 0 if the edit text field is 0 else, you will parse the value entered to a double.

Assuming you want to consider a 0 if there is a blank edit text field.

========================================================================
UPDATE

```
if(sideAObj.getText().toString() != ""){
       double sideA = Double.parseDouble(sideAObj.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: Did you check the same for sideObjA as well?

Comment: Did the same for sideObjA as well still doesn't work

Comment: Which field are you leaving blank? sideA, sideB or sideC?

Comment: I'm leaving sideA blank

Comment: I didn't quite get your functionality., correct me if I am wrong. I guess you enter numbers in sideB and sideC correct? And what are you supposed to enter in sideA to work and calculate properly?

Comment: sideA has nothing inputted, while sideB and sideC have numbers

Comment: Then what's the use of sideA field?

Comment: It's for later I want to be able to do the same process for sideB and sideC

Comment: Firstly, if you leave it as blank., your code must fail at this line itself.... double sideA = Double.parseDouble(sideAObj.getText().toString()); as it cannot parse a blank to double.

Comment: Ok so how do I prevent it from failing?

Comment: You can't. You need to add a check before assigning it to sideA. So what you can do is that you will only parse the entered value to a double if it is not a blank value. See my updated answer above

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution for this problem would be to check each edittext whether they are blank or not and then perform the task.

Get the value of each Edittext to a int variable and then use loop and with the help of edittext.length() method verify if it is equal to 0, if yes, then assign a value to 0 to a new global variable, else assign the exact value to global variable.

and then perform the calculation with the new variables.

Sample code for better understanding :-

```
String a = et.getText().toString();
            int l = a.length();

            if (l == 0){
                // set the value of global variable = 0;
            } else {
                // set the value of global variable = a  {Actual Digit}
            }
```